# Why can't gdb show debug info?

Tags: c++, gcc, gdb, kernel, cross-compiling

Here is my g++:

```
$ /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1-for-linux32/bin/i586-pc-linux-g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1-for-linux32/bin/i586-pc-linux-g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1-for-linux32/libexec/gcc/i586-pc-linux/4.8.1/lto-wrapper
Target: i586-pc-linux
Configured with: ../gcc-4.8.1/configure --target=i586-pc-linux --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --prefix=/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1-for-linux32 --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-threads=posix --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-clocale=gnu --disable-bootstrap
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.1 (GCC)
```

gdb:

```
$ i386-linux-gdb -v
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.7.1
This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0 --target=i386-linux".
```

CXX_FLAGS:

```
-ffreestanding -O0 -Wall -Wextra -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -ggdb -nostdlib -std=c++11 -m32
```

generate `kernel.bin`:

```
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1-for-linux32/bin/i586-pc-linux-g++ -I. -Iinclude -Ikernel -ffreestanding -O0 -Wall -Wextra -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -ggdb -nostdlib -std=c++11 -m32 -e main -Ttext 0x100000 -o generated/kernel.bin generated/kernel/init/kernelMain.o generated/kernel/memoryManage/memoryManage.o
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1-for-linux32/bin/i586-pc-linux-objdump -S -D generated/kernel.bin > generated/kernel.dump
```

I use qemu-i386 to load my toy OS, then my bootloader will parse `kernel.bin`, puts segments into memory. Then I start gdb in my host OS (OS X 10.11), execute:

```
file ./generated/kernel.bin
target remote localhost:1234
b initMemory
c
```

I can successfully stop at function `initMemory` which is in `memoryManage.o`.

```
8: x/i 0x100000 + $eip
   0x100010 <initMemory()>: push   %ebp
```

However when I execute `n` or `s` or `p` it doesn't work. I can only use `si` `ni`

```
(gdb) n
Cannot find bounds of current function
(gdb) s
Cannot find bounds of current function
(gdb) p memoryInfoAddr
No symbol "memoryInfoAddr" in current context.
```

How can I fix this problem? Is it caused by mismatch of i586 g++ and i386 gdb, or mismatch of gcc 4.8.1 and gdb 7.7.1?

Comment: Please review your command line to verify that you are telling the *compiler* to generate debug information.  With some compilers, the option is "-g".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I have the -ggdb, and the dump file from kernel.bin has many debug sections, such as debug_info, debug_line ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I find out the problem. gdb use `%eip` to find instructions, however in my kernel it should use `%cs:%eip`. After setting `%cs` to `0`, gdb works as expected.